# event is only triggered when fired twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I don't know why but the first time I click the event target, it doesn't take effect, you have to click the event target twice to take effect but the result is opposite. Consider this experiment that I created using checkbox:

```js
$('.label-button').on('click', checkboxStatus);

function checkboxStatus(e) {
  var $evt = $(e.target);

  if($evt.next().is(':checked')) {
    $('.message').find('.status').text('checked');
  } else {
    $('.message').find('.status').text('not checked');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="cbox" class="label-button" style="display:inline-block;padding:0.5rem 0.7rem;color:#fff;background:#21a1e1;cursor:pointer;">Click to check</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="cbox" />

<div class="message" style="display:block; margin-top:10px;">Checkbox is "<span class="status">not checked</span>"</div>
```

The first time you click the button, the `.status` says it's still "not checked" though the checkbox is actually checked. The second time you click the button, it shows the changes, but opposite. The checkbox is checked but the status is "not checked"; the checkbox is unchecked but the status is "checked". I tried to add `e.stopPropagation()` but it didn't work.

How can I make this right?

Answer (score 0):

By the time click event on label is invoked, `input` state is not changed hence you are observing such inconsistency.

Bind `change` event on the `input` element instead of `click` event on the `label`!

```js
$('#cbox').on('change', checkboxStatus);

function checkboxStatus() {
  $('.message').find('.status').text(this.checked ? 'checked' : 'not checked');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="cbox" class="label-button" style="display:inline-block;padding:0.5rem 0.7rem;color:#fff;background:#21a1e1;cursor:pointer;">Click to check</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="cbox" />

<div class="message" style="display:block; margin-top:10px;">Checkbox is "<span class="status">not checked</span>"</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the event with `change` instead of `click`.
2. And apply the change event on `input:checkbox` not with label
3. finally change the checking if condition like this `$evt.is(':checked')`

```js
$('#cbox').on('change', checkboxStatus);

function checkboxStatus(e) {
  var $evt = $(e.target);

  if($evt.is(':checked')) {
    $('.message').find('.status').text('checked');
  } else {
    $('.message').find('.status').text('not checked');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="cbox" class="label-button" style="display:inline-block;padding:0.5rem 0.7rem;color:#fff;background:#21a1e1;cursor:pointer;">Click to check</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="cbox" />

<div class="message" style="display:block; margin-top:10px;">Checkbox is "<span class="status">not checked</span>"</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
  $('.label-button').on('click', checkboxStatus);

  function checkboxStatus(e) {
    var $evt = $(e.target).next();
    
    if( $evt.prop('checked') ) {
      $('.message').find('.status').text('not checked');
    } else {
      $('.message').find('.status').text('checked');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="cbox" class="label-button" style="display:inline-block;padding:0.5rem 0.7rem;color:#fff;background:#21a1e1;cursor:pointer;">Click to check</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="cbox" />

<div class="message" style="display:block; margin-top:10px;">Checkbox is "<span class="status">not checked</span>"</div>
```